# SQL Server Procedure returns multiple tables - Insert results into tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a procedure that returns multiple tables; eg:

```
PROCEDURE Something AS
BEGIN
 SELECT 1,2,3
 SELECT 4,5
 SELECT 9,10,11
END
```

I would like to take each table from the result and insert it into a series of tables/temp tables - one for each record set.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the overall goal? This may be something that is better suited to "front-end" coding

Answer (score 1):

if you Union the results together they would come out as one result set.

your second query only has 2 columns but this would need to be resolved either way as you put it into a table.

Comment: I had considered that however unions are not possible because the schema differs

Comment: Then what are you expecting to happen by putting them all in one table?

Comment: I agree with @IC,  if you are putting them into one table, you would have to account for the different schema in some way.

Comment: Sorry if i wasnt clear; I would like each set in its own table.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the temporary tables within the stored proc and push the records into that. If you are using the same session , the table would be available after the stored proc is finished.

Or you could create the temp tables before hand and call the sp to populate them.

Comment: If you create the #TempTables in the child SProc are they still in scope for the Parent?  I have a feeling they have to be created in the Parent, and then used in the Child, for the results to be in scope for the Parent again

Comment: It works both ways. Since temp tables are like global variables witin the session , they can be seen from everywhere in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Multiple Active Resultsets (MARS).  It may do what you are looking for.

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/multiple-active-result-sets-mars

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/01/MARSIntroduction1.aspx

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought MARS allowed launching a second query before the first one had been fully retrieved - rather than just multiple resultsets from a single command execution?

Comment: You may be absolutely right.  I just figured that if there was any way to do what the OP was trying to do then chances are it would be using MARS.